# Attach event handlers to multiple textboxes (with similar patterned id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have several textboxes that are generated dynamically based on some results I get from another source.  I want to add some event handlers to these textboxes to catch any `keypress`, and ensure that anything entered is numeric.

I generate these textboxes based on the length of an array within a JSON response, like so:

```
for(i=0;i<data.routesout.length;i++)
{           
            content += '<label for="route' + i + '">' + data.routesout[i].name + '(%)</label>';
            content += '<input type="text" name="route' + i + '" id="route' + i + '" value="' + data.routesout[i].percent>';            
}
```

How can I attach a single event handler to all of these potential inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged the question with jQuery, so I wonder why you're not using the library to build your content:

```
var content = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.routesout.length; ++i) {
  content.push($('<label/>', { 'for': 'route' + i, text: data.routesout[i].name }));
  content.push($('<input/>', { change: yourEventHandler, type: 'text', name: 'route' + i, id: 'route' + i, value: date.routesout[i].percent, change: yourEventHandler }));
}
```

By doing it that way, you can bind the handler element by element as you construct them. (I used "change" as an example, but you could bind handlers for whatever event you want in the same way.)

At the end, you can append all the created elements however you want, or you could append them as you go instead of building an array.

Comment: I'm pretty new to jQuery (and web programming in general, more of a desktop .NET developer if I'm honest) so I didn't know you could do that.  I really like it though, a lot neater.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [*starts with*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('input[id^="route"]').keyup(function(){...
```

Note that if you're creating these on the fly, you might need to attach the event using [*live*](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('input[id^="route"]').live('keyup', function(){...
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
for(i=0;i<data.routesout.length;i++){           
  content += '<label for="route' + i + '">' + data.routesout[i].name + '(%)</label>';
  content += '<input onkeypress="doSomething(this)" type="text" name="route' + i + '" id="route' + i + '" value="' + data.routesout[i].percent + '>';            
}

function doSomething(element){
  /* this function will be called when user presess key inside a textbox */
}
```